# html code renders as plain text inside php

Tags: php

I am trying to send an email here, using the code below:
I am expecting the anchor tag to be rendered as a link, but it is just displaying the anchor link as plain text. How can I render it as html instead of plain text?

```
<?php
// the message

$msg = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Click here to visit stackoverflow</a>';

// send email
mail("test@yahoo.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

Comment: Add proper headers to send html email

Comment: I agree with @Dagon, you'll have to apply the correct headers... You have to 'tell' the mail reader that you're sending HTML content. It doesn't detect it by itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer mail function documentation on php.net, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You code should include headers:

```
<?php 
$msg = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Click here to visit stackoverflow</a>';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // send email
    mail("test@yahoo.com","My subject", $msg, $headers);
```

A more detailed example taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php:

```
<?php
    // multiple recipients
    $to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
    $to .= 'wez@example.com';

    // subject
    $subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

    // message
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without defining the `content type`

> php dont know if it is a HTML mail

so `define content-type` in at the top of your php code so that php will render it using HTML format.

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: You are right i wonder why someone down-voted this.  Unless it is specified php considers it as a plain text mail

Answer (score -1):

I belive this might give you an Idea what you would be looking for. My Example is using headers not only to tell Content Type Whereas this might help to understand that message should not deliver in the spam folders.

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once('Mail/mime.php');

    $to = "test@yahoo.com";
    $subject = "My Subject";
    $header = "from: Some Test Name <test@yahoo.com> \r"."<br >";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \r"."<br >";
    $header .= "Return-Path: <test@yahoo.com> \r"."<br >"; //you can change it too
    $header .= "X-Priority: 1 (Highest) \r"."<br >"; 
    $header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High \r"."<br >";
    $header .= "Importance: High \r"."<br >"; 
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r"."<br >";

//Making sure that message should deliver and should not go in the Spam folder.

    $message = "<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Click here to visit stackoverflow</a>
</body>
</html>"

    $from = "Some Test Name <test@yahoo.com>";
    $host = "smtp.yahoo.com"; //I am not sure about yahoo SMTP
    $port = "587";
    $username1 = "test@yahoo.com"; 
    $password1 = "test1234"; //Password
    $crlf = chr(10);
    $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
    $mime->setHTMLBody($message);
    $body = $mime->getMessageBody();
    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username1, 'password' => $password1));
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body );
?>
```

Comment: he is using mail() not what ever that is surpose to be